# Null Pointer Execption in setting canvas to image view

Tags: android, canvas, android-imageview

I have a path drawn on the canvas and I want it to appear in an ImageView but I am getting a NullPointerException as show in then stack trace:

```
Process: com.example.abcd, PID: 9233
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.abcd/com.example.abcd.NewTest}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.abcd.NewTest.onCreate(NewTest.java:28)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
... 11 more
```

This is how I am doing it:

```
public class NewTest extends Activity{
public static ImageView im1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new NewAnimation(this));

    ImageView im = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    im.setImageBitmap(NewAnimation.bitMap); 
}




public static class NewAnimation extends View{

Paint paint;
Context context;
int screenW, screenH;
Path path; 
float X,Y;
public static Bitmap bitMap;
Canvas canvas;


public NewAnimation(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE); 
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10); 
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    path = new Path();
}


public NewAnimation(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    path = new Path();

}


@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    screenW = w;
    screenH = h;
    X = screenW/4;
    Y = screenH/2;

    path.moveTo(X, Y);

    Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; 
    bitMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 1000, conf); 
    canvas = new Canvas(bitMap); 
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { 
    super.onDraw(canvas); 

        path.lineTo(X+20, Y);
path.lineTo(X+20, Y+20);

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint); 
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitMap, 500, 500, paint); 

    invalidate();
} 

}
}
```

Is it beacause of error in setting the bitmap to the imageview? What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: can you post stacktrace?

Comment: @bipin Stack trace updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error lies here

```
setContentView(new NewAnimation(this));
ImageView im = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

You are setting a customview as your contentview and then finding the imageView1 which doesnt exist there. So its getting null value.

Set

```
setContentView(R.layout.layout_which_contains_imageView1).
im.setImageBitmap((new NewAnimation(this)).bitMap); //ignore the static warning
```

Move these 3 lines in your 1st constructor

```
Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
bitMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 1000, conf);
canvas = new Canvas(bitMap);
```

Followed by addition of this line below those three

```
draw(canvas);
```

Regards

Comment: @MandarKakde I have rectified this, but still that does not solve the problem. The path is not getting drawn in the imageView.

Comment: Doesn't help. Nothing appears on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting NPE because you are setting

```
new NewAnimation(this);
```

in **setContentView()**, and then you are finding the imageview id. You must have defined the imageview in some xml, so set that xml layout in setContentView().

Comment: on setting the xml nothing appears on the screen! The path drawn should have app read there.

Comment: @Sparkplug that is separate issue, but the NPE was because your imageview was null.

Comment: @Sparkplug why are you instanciating a static inner class?

Comment: I am trying to set the bitmap to the image view from the Activity class.

Comment: @Sparkplug if you have set the xml in the setContentView(), then your paint object is not getting initialized, thats why your path is not getting drawn. I hope, now it will help you and you can accept my answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45109/discussion-between-amit-singh-and-sparkplug)

Answer (score 0):

There is problem in this part:

```
ImageView im = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

Since you didn't call: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`, activity_main was not inflated and findViewbyID returned null.

So now do this:

```
View base = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main,null);//I am assuming that imageView1 is in activity_main.xml file
ImageView im = (ImageView)base.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

UPDATE:
remove `invalidate()` form `onDraw()` method. It creates recursive loop.

Comment: I have added this, but still it does not solve the problem. The path is not getting drawn in the imageView and the screen is blank.

Comment: Now does your application crash? or it just shows blank screen?

Comment: Remove canvas attribute from NewAnimation class, it is useless. Also remove `invalidate()` from `onDraw()` method because it would be recursive. I have updated this in my answer too. Good luck